# Duplicate results in list of unanswered questions in Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

While browsing through the list of unanswered questions with the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, I found two exactly same results.

Here is the screenshot. Compare the first 2 results in the screenshot.

[image: Bug: Duplicate rows in the list of questions]

I am not sure if it's a reproducible bug or not.

Comment: Does this persist after a refresh?

Comment: Proper pagination is rocket-science on a web site where unanswered questions get added at a high rate.  The code has several glitches, posts also go missing.  Previous bug reports about it have been ignored, they probably don't want to touch it with anything less than a 10 foot pole.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior with the CSS tag in Unanswered Questions under [No Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/css?tab=noanswers). [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGK2S.png). The duplicate listing continues to persist after several minutes, despite refreshing.